# Odoo 9 form view custom saving method

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

We're trying to implement a custom reservation-type solution in our installation of Odoo 9. The solution includes a `Reservation` model and a `Session` model. One of the functions for a `Reservation` is to operate as an associative container for `Sessions`. The `Session` model has a `Many2one` field that links it to the `Reservation` model.

At this point, we have the models defined and a standard form view that allows us to create a new reservation. However, we want the view to include a dropdown widget that allows us to select the number of accompanying sessions, and we want the reservation save functionality to create the appropriate number of sessions.

There are two parts we're struggling with in implementing this:

- How can we include a widget (dropdown menu with numbers 1-8) that isn't actually tied to a model field? The value would be released as soon as the command mentioned in the next point is executed.
- <strike>Is there a way to overwrite the standard save functionality to execute custom code (creating the number of Sessions corresponding to the value of the custom widget and prepopulating them with standard values), or do we have to create a completely custom action and hide the default save button on the form view?</strike> ***We have figured this out, as you can see in our code.***

We don't need anyone to code this out for us, but since we're new to the platform pointing us in the general direction of appropriate methodologies would be great.

**Edit:**

Here is the relevant code we have so far:

**models.py**

```
class ResNumber(models.Model):
    _name = 'restest.res_num'
    name = fields.Char(string="Number to book", required=True)
    num = fields.Integer(string="Number", required=True)

class Reservation(models.Model):
    _name = 'restest.reservations'
    name = fields.Char(string="Title", required=True)
    num_booked = fields.Many2one('restest.res_num', ondelete='set null', string="Number to book")
    slot_id = fields.Many2one('restest.slots', ondelete='set null', string="Slot ID")
    session_ids = fields.One2many('restest.sessions', 'reservation_id', string="Session IDs")
    customer = fields.Many2one('res.partner', ondelete='set null', string="Customer")

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        res_id = super(Reservation, self).create(vals)
        numValue = res_id.num_booked.num
        resIdValue = res_id.id
        start = 1
        while start <= numValue:
            self.env['restest.sessions'].create({'name': start, 'reservation_id': resIdValue})
            start = start + 1
        return res_id

class Session(models.Model):
    _name = 'restest.sessions'
    name = fields.Char(string="Title", required=True)
    reservation_id = fields.Many2one('restest.reservations', ondelete='set null', string ="Reservation ID")
```

**views.xml**

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="reservation_create_view">
            <field name="name">reservation.form</field>
            <field name="model">restest.reservations</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Make a Reservation">
                    <sheet>
                        <group>
                            <field name="name"/>
                            <field name="slot_id"/>
                            <field name="num_booked"/>
                        </group>
                    </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="make_res_action">
            <field name="name">Make a Reservation</field>
            <field name="res_model">restest.reservations</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="reservation_create_view"/>
        </record>
```

**defaultData.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <openerp>
    <record id="first_cat" model="restest.res_num">
        <field name="name">1</field>
        <field name="num">1</field>
    </record>
    <record id="second_cat" model="restest.res_num">
        <field name="name">2</field>
        <field name="num">2</field>
    </record>
    <record id="third_cat" model="restest.res_num">
        <field name="name">3</field>
        <field name="num">3</field>
    </record>
    <record id="fourth_cat" model="restest.res_num">
        <field name="name">4</field>
        <field name="num">4</field>
    </record>
</openerp>
```

So the test implementation here is pretty simple. We created the `ResNumber` model and prefilled it with entries from 1-4. The `Many2one` field in the `Reservation` model is the current means by which the user can select how many sessions to reserve. We overrode the default create command to create the number of sessions based on the value of the `ResNumber` field.

However, what we are wanting is to remove the `ResNumber` model entirely. It's not a good database practice to store this number in the table since it can be derived through an alternate query. What we are wanting to do is include a field on the form view for the `Reservation` model with the number selection and then have the value be discarded as soon as the `Session` instances are created. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: you should show your code and your current attempt so we can help you

Comment: Great point @danidee. It's now added, and I should add since last night we've solved the second question.

Comment: are you trying to change the number of records in the drop box of   many2one field   <field name="slot_id"/>  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a selection field and set the store property to False

```
fields.Selection([(1, '1'), 
                  (2, '2'), 
                  (3, '3'), 
                  (4, '4')], string='ResNumber' store=False)
```

it's pretty straight forward, in the case of `'1'` is displayed in the front-end to the user, but on the back end the value returned is the integer `1` and when you set store to False you're telling odoo not to store the value in the db (it should probably be used just to display information to the user or form some sort of calculation or logic)

Comment: We got sidetracked and this project got put on hold, but I was finally able to test it out. Thank you for your clear and concise answer.